# Adding Typescript to an existing React application one file at a time?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've recently started working on a new project at work which has been utilizing React and JavaScript.

As someone who mainly used TypeScript in previous projects I've been struggling a bit with how loose everything is.

If I were able to, I would just convert the whole project to TypeScript however some of my coworkers aren't familiar with it.

My question is, lets say for example, I needed to add a new component somewhere on the page, would it work if I added TypeScript to the project with npm and had only one file as `.tsx`? Of course when building the project for production I would run `TSC` to compile it back into vanilla JS.

Also thought I should just point out I’m not looking to convert the whole project to TypeScript, just a few here and there.

Thanks!

Comment: with just a few changes in your config this is easily possible. Just changed my whole project to typescript file by file over 5 weeks. :)

Comment: read this: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-migrate-a-react-app-to-typescript/

Comment: This is available here: [add typescript to existing react app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5wb5N1MAKQ)

Comment: @ffx292 did you found any suitable answer? cause none of the answers / comments works for me

Comment: I found that just simply switching the react project over to Typescript, and then in the tsconfig file, selecting the option allowJs, works.

When you npm run, it'll compile both ts and js files, that was how I just slowly changed it over.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your project as if you were going to convert everything to typescript, make sure you have `allowJs` and `checkJs` set to true in your tsconfig file, make sure all variations of TS strict mode are off, then convert as many or as few (or even none) js files to ts.